# Determine$\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)(f(x))^s)dx,s\in \mathbb Z$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow  \mathbb R$ be continuously differentable and $f(x)>0 , x\in [a,b]$.
>
> Determine the following integral:
>
> $(1)\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)(f(x))^s)dx,s\in \mathbb Z$

At first it seems as if I should use substitution so that I get

> $(2)\int_{a}^{b}u^5 du,s\in \mathbb Z$ where $u=f(x)$.

But my textbook

(Rudin: http://dangtuanhiep.files.wordpress.com/2008/09/principles_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf ,p.141 in PDF, p.132 in book)

states that in order for the equation $(1)=(2)$ to hold, $f(x)$ needs to be strictly increasing. But according to the exercise $f(x)$ does, in fact, not have to be strictly increasing, for, e.g., a constant function $f(x)=3$ meets all the requirements of $f$ but is not strictly increasing.

So far I figuered that

$f(x)$ is continuous (since differentable), $f'(x)$ exists and is continuous,

$F(x)$ exists (since $f$ is continuous) and is strictly monotonically increasing (since $F'(x)=f(x)>0$) but it doesn't help me at all.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply proceed by direct inspection:
$$
f'(x)(f(x))^s = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x)^{s+1}}{s+1},
$$
and apply the Fundamental Theorem. 
Technically speaking you are perfectly right: integrals of the form
$$
\int g'(f(x))f'(x)\, dx
$$
are solved immediately by $g(f(x))+C$, but the substitution $u=f(x)$ is not necessarily bijective.

Comment: So instead of using u-sub I just say that this is its antiderivate (obviously) and then proceeding as usual? But u sub should be possible in this case, since its soultion is equal to what we desire. However, f(x) is not strictly increasing so why can we use it, even though this requirement isn't met?

Comment: It is a long story... Theoretically, a substitution in a definite integral must be a *real* change of variable (bijective, differentiable). If we only look for primitives, any device that leads to a primitive is admissible, and many books allow non-bijective substitutions in *indefinite* integrals.